# Induced electric field inside an inductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, potential, electromagnetic-induction

Okay so I was recently taught about inductors and how they generate an emf which opposes the increasing magnetic flux due to an increasing current.

In an LR circuit, the current flows through the inductor, creates a TIME VARYING magnetic field in the coil which must be opposed by some induced emf.  What confuses me is the potential drop created by the inductor. Magnetic fields which change with time induce an electric field which does forms closed loops. Will such an electric field be generated along the coil and the wires of the circuit. Can I compare this circuit to two cells connected to each other in series with opposite directions of emf ?

(Edit)
Why do we say that an EMF is generated across an inductor. Saying that an EMF is generated implies that some work is done by a Non-electric Force to create a potential difference. I know that induced electric field is not comparable to an electrostatic field created by a charge separation (battery) but isn't it an electric field ?

Comment: We use EMF to denote $\int Edl$ and voltage to denote $-\int Edl$